# NoSuchElementException in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to open a website using Selenium, find a specific search box within it and fill it with a company name (MAGAZINE LUIZA S.A. in the example) and then click the "Search" button right next to the search box, since it will not work if I just hit "enter".

```
nav = webdriver.Edge()

nav.implicitly_wait(10)

nav.get('http://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/produtos-e-servicos/negociacao/renda-variavel/empresas-listadas.htm')

nav.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/label/span[1]/input[1]").send_keys('MAGAZINE LUIZA S.A.')

nav.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input').click()
```

And I get the Xpath of the search bar and search button by inspecting them and "copying full Xpath" in Microsoft Edge.

Problem is I get this error:

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/form/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/label/span[1]/input[1]"}
> (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=91.0.864.54)

But I have verified that I have copied and pasted the correct Xpaths for both the commands. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle iframe, that XPath is relative to iframe.

This is your modified code

```py
nav = webdriver.Edge()

nav.implicitly_wait(10)

nav.get('http://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/produtos-e-servicos/negociacao/renda-variavel/empresas-listadas.htm')


iframe = nav.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/form/section/div/div/div/iframe')
nav.switch_to.frame(iframe)
inp = nav.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/label/span[1]/input[1]")

inp.send_keys('MAGAZINE LUIZA S.A.')

nav.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input').click()
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! How did you find the XPath of the iframe element?

Comment: just find the iframe, in which your input is, and just copy the full XPath.